# How to populate an input field based on select box and viceversa

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to populate a select box and an input field.

Meaning,

1. Whenever someone tries to choose a country, I set the relevant currency in the input box and display country+currency in output.
2. Whenever someone tries to enter a currency, I set the country in the option box and display country+currency in output.

My Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {           
    $scope.$watch('countrySelect', function () {
        for ($i = 0; $i < arr.length; $i++) {
            var temp = arr[$i]['select'];
            if (temp === $scope.countrySelect) {
                $scope.outputCountry = arr[$i].country + arr[$i].currency;
                $scope.countryCurrency = arr[$i].currency;
            }
        }
    });

    $scope.$watch('countryCurrency', function () {
        for ($i = 0; $i < arr.length; $i++) {
            var temp = arr[$i]['currency'];
            if (temp === $scope.countryCurrency) {
                $scope.outputCountry = arr[$i].country + $scope.countryCurrency;
                $scope.countrySelect = arr[$i].country;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Corresponding div:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form action="#">
        <select ng-model="countrySelect" ng-init="countrySelect = 11">
            <option value="11">US</option>
            <option value="12">UK</option>
        </select>
        <input ng-model="countryCurrency" />
        <input ng-model="outputCountry" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I've come up with [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hGgKRz2LhM44jwOJu307?p=preview).

1. Are there any better way of achieving the same without using `$scope.watch` and firing it multiple times?
2. During the load(before choosing any country by default), `$scope.watch` doesn't fire and the values are not populated at all.

Any pointers here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write "usd" or "sek" in first input field, or select country in selectbox.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.countryCurrency = "";
    $scope.outputCountry = "";
    $scope.countries = [
        {
            name: "Sweden",
            currency: "SEK"
        },
        {
            name: "United States",
            currency: "USD"
        }
    ];
    $scope.selected = {
        country: $scope.countries[0].name
    };

    $scope.$watch("selected.country", function()
    {
        var country = $scope.countries.find(function(country)
        {
            return country.name == $scope.selected.country;
        });

        if(country)
        {
            $scope.outputCountry = country.name + country.currency;
            $scope.countryCurrency = country.currency;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.outputCountry = "";
            $scope.countryCurrency = "";
        }
    });

    $scope.$watch("countryCurrency", function()
    {
        var country = $scope.countries.find(function(country)
        {
            return country.currency == $scope.countryCurrency.toUpperCase().trim();
        });

        if(country)
        {
            $scope.outputCountry = country.name + $scope.countryCurrency;
            $scope.selected.country = country.name;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.outputCountry = "";
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form action="#">
        <select ng-model="selected.country">
            <option ng-repeat="country in countries" ng-value="country.name">{{ country.name }}</option>
        </select>
        <input ng-model="countryCurrency" />
        <input ng-model="outputCountry" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking out for. Thanks.

Comment: Sweet! No problem :)

Comment: there is a `ng-change=countryChanged()` function. Where is this used ?

Comment: Nowhere, You can use either ng-change on a $scope-function or $scope.$watch, they pretty much give the same result. I must have thought of using ng-change first then changed my mind to use $watch :P I am sure there are more clean way to write this as well, kind of wrote it in a haste :)

Comment: Edited to remove ng-change.

Comment: your 1st watch triggers your 2nd watch and 2nd triggers 1st - you cant write things this way

Comment: hmm you're right. I added a console.log in each $watch to check if an endless loop is happening but it isn't. Is angular handling this internally some way?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
Select your favorite fruit:
<select id="mySelect" onclick="myFunction()" >
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>

<input type = "text" id = "TextBox1">


</form>




<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = x;
    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this what are you looking for??